# breed in netlogo- How to make various agents using one breed

Tags: netlogo

I want to create various agents from one breed.

like :

breed [ nodes node]

Question:
using this one breed " node ", I want to create some nodes as home, some as consumers, some as cars etc. Is it possible? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing stops you from creating your own variable (e.g. `kind`) to specify the type of each node:

```
breed [ nodes node ]
nodes-own [ kind ]

to setup
  clear-all
  creates-nodes 10 [ set kind "home" ]
  creates-nodes 10 [ set kind "consumer" ]
  creates-nodes 10 [ set kind "car" ]
end
```

That being said... *why would you ever want to do that?*

NetLogo breeds are the right tool to represent different kinds of agents. If all these things are different, they should probably belong to different breeds. Much better, in my opinion, to do:

```
breed [ homes a-home ]
breed [ consumers consumer ]
breed [ cars car ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-homes 10
  create-consumers 10
  create-cars 10
end
```

Note that all these things can still be connected by links (i.e. be nodes in a network) even if they are of different breeds.

If there is some other downside of breeds that you are worried about, please let us know in the comments. We can probably alleviate your concerns.